# GET imageRoute 404 (Not Found) on Laravel

Tags: laravel, routes, location, laravel-5.4, src

I have a Laravel project that I've mainly been working on it's back end, but now I copied the layouts from another project which has two images on the header. This is one of them:

```
<img class="img-logo" src="imagenes/temp_imgs/logo temporal.png">
```

The images on my old project are stored on **public/imagenes/temp_imgs/**, so I created those same folders on my new project and stored the images there. But when I run it I get the following error:

> GET http://localhost:8000/competencias/imagenes/temp_imgs/logo%20temporal.png 404 (Not Found)

It seems as if it isn't looking for the images on my public folder but rather on the location of the view (competencias), the view is competencias/crear.blade.php

I don't remember much from the configuration on the old project, I only now I ran `npm install` on both at creation, so both have bootstrap and vue. But that's al I now, **maybe you can help me see if a configuration file on the old project is making the image src point to the public folder,** or figuring out what's generating the error.

**EDIT:**

If I paste one of the files from my old project to my new one the images are shown. If I rename one of the files from my new project and give it a name of a file from my old project the images are also shown! I hope this helps in figuring this thing out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in laravel 5.4 you will not able to see image as your link
route will lock your every public folder

```
http://localhost:8000/competencias/imagenes/temp_imgs/logo%20temporal.png
```

just try to use like that

```
<img class="img-logo" src="{{ url('imagenes/temp_imgs/logo temporal.png') }}">
```

or

```
<img class="img-logo" src="{{ asset('imagenes/temp_imgs/logo temporal.png') }}">
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `{{ asset('imagenes/temp_imgs/logo temporal.png') }}`

For all assets use `{{asset(....)}}` to solve all problems that maybe appear for you

Hope help you